# Get the newest records from mysql table by column name

Tags: mysql

I need to get the newest records from the below table for each indicator name, for example the GI of data 2015-11-16 and GO of 2015-11-14.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

[image: 1]

Comment: This is the most frequently asked question under this tag on SO. It is also correctly answered quite often. It's a travesty of this forum's intentions then that only one of the answers so far suggested below is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this and is called `group wise maximum`
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

```
select t1.* from table_name t1
join (
 select indicator_name,max(indicator_date) as indicator_date from table_name
 group by indicator_name
)t2
on t1.indicator_name = t2.indicator_name 
and t1.indicator_date = t2.indicator_date
```

Comment: If the indicator_date is unique for each indicator_name then this would be my choice of solution

Answer (score 1):

If you want the latest row for each `indicator_name`, then you can give a row number to each row group by the `indicator_name` and order by `indicator_date` in descending order.

**Query**

```
select t1.indicator_id, 
       t1.indicator_name, 
       t1.indicator_value, 
       t1.indicator_date
from 
(
     select indicator_id, 
            indicator_name, 
            indicator_value, 
            indicator_date, 
    (
        case indicator_name when @curA 
        then @curRow := @curRow + 1 
        else @curRow := 1 and @curA := indicator_name end 
    ) + 1 as rn 
    from tblIndicators t, 
    (select @curRow := 0, @curA := '') r 
    order by indicator_name,indicator_date desc 
)t1 
where t1.rn = 1;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3421e/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from yourtable
GROUP BY indicator_name
ORDER BY indicator_date DESC
```

Comment: This is wrong. The GROUP BY operates before the ORDER BY, meaning that a random date will be selected. I'd love to know the justification for the upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY indicator_name,indicator_date DESC
```